# Initialize multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

I have this matrix that holds a 4x4 array of `double`:

```
typedef struct {
    double data[4][4];
} mat;
```

And here I declare my `mat`

```
mat m1;
```

And i want to initialize my `mat` with zeros:

```
double data[4][4] = { { 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 } };
MAT_A.data = data;
```

And got this error:

> expression must be a modifiable lvalue

And:

> '=': left operand must be l-value

I also tried this:

```
MAT_A->data = data;
```

**EDIT:**

Another question is how to initiate `mat` ?

Comment: You'll better improve your question to give an actual [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot assign an array to a struct, nor an array to an array. The C syntax does not allow it.

And if you want to *initialize* a variable, you should not use *assignment*. These are different things; `MAT_A.data = data;` is assignment. This is initialization:

```
mat m =
{
  .data = { { 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 } }
};
```

As for assignment, what you can do is assign a struct to a struct, for example by using a compound literal:

```
m = (mat) 
{
  .data = { { 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0 } }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want to initiate my mat with zeros:

Then you could simply code:

```
mat m1 = {0};
```

or

```
double data[4][4] = {0};
```

(and `{}` instead of `{0}` would also practically work, even if non-standard)

and you could even use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) to clear the zone (with `<string.h>` standard header):

```
double data[4][4];
memset (&data, 0, sizeof(data));
```

or

```
memset (&m1, 0, sizeof(m1));
```

BTW, optimizing compilers like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (invoked as `gcc -O2 -march=native`) are likely to generate in practice the same machine code in all cases, if `m1` or `data` is an [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) (on your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)).

However, assignments of arrays (`m1.data = data;`) is illegal (because arrays decay into pointers).

And your title is wrong: C has no multi-dimensional arrays, only (mono-dimensional) arrays (perhaps arrays of arrays, arrays of structures, etc...).

Comment: I take it you mean `{0}` since `{}` would be invalid C.

Comment: And i need to initiate first my mat ? how can i do that ?

Comment: Didn't I answer to that in my answer? Please improve first your question by giving an [MCVE]. Then I could improve my answer !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your initialization of the array `data`, but in the following assignment:

```
MAT_A.data = data;
```

In order to copy an array you need to copy the elements of the array individually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      MAT_A.data[i][j] = data[i][j];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly initialize the array as follows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        MAT_A.data[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is assignment, not initialization.